# Using webform master page in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webforms

I have tried implementing [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx), but the extension methods are not working when I rewrite them in VB. I am trying to use a corporate master page in my MVC3 application. Right now I have my `.Master` and my `.ascx` page. I am confused on how to get it to show in my razor view.

my `.ascx` page:

```
<%@ control Language="VB" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentArea" runat="server">
<div>
Hello World

</div>
</asp:Content>
```

When I run it, it gives me this error: `Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.`

I use my `_ViewStart.vbhtml`to call on the `.ascx` page.

Comment: Is it really so hard for you to not just rewrite your master page into a mvc layout page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to hack webforms objects to work with MVC3 is only going to cause you trouble down the road. Redo the file as an MVC3 layout using razor.

**Edit:** added 
Layout File Tutorials:
[Making layout pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3razor_topic2.aspx)
[Understanding Layout Files](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx)
[Layouts and Sections](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)

Comment: I've tried that. Maybe I'm doing it wrong? Can I do the equivalent of registering a namespace in the razor view layout file? Is there a tutorial on how to redo the master pages that you recommend?

Comment: These are great thanks! I do still have a question about converting some webform tags to razor. `<cmg:cmgHeaderX id="HeaderX" designer="IntranetHeader.htm" runat="server" />` this is what I am having trouble with converting to razor. I have inherited the correct namespace, but I don't know how to set the designer.

Comment: Is that a custom control? You might have to convert it into a partial, or find another way to achieve that functionality. You cannot (you can, but again you shouldnt) use webform controls in mvc.

Comment: @gblock, You have to understand that MVC3 and Webforms do not play nice together. If you are converting an app to mvc3, you will be redoing large section of the code.  Any code specific to webforms should not be used.

Comment: Yes it is, ok I will try to figure it out. I work in a big company and they don't like change very much :/. I'll do what I can thanks!